# What exactly is represented by the "Compilation" object provided in a Roslyn IIncrementalGenerator?

Tags: c#, roslyn, .net-standard

According to the [Incremental Generators documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/incremental-generators.md), an incremental generator will be called exactly once by the host regardless of how many projects are involved in the compilation:

> IIncrementalGenerator has an Initialize method that is called by the host exactly once, regardless of the number of further compilations that may occur. For instance a host with multiple loaded projects may share the same generator instance across multiple projects, and will only call Initialize a single time for the lifetime of the host.
>
> [incremental-generators.md § Pipeline based execution](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/incremental-generators.md#pipeline-based-execution)

However, in practice, `context.CompilationProvider` is an `IncrementalValueProvider<Compilation>` providing a **single** compilation object.

This single compilation object has an `Assembly` property which is documented as...

> The IAssemblySymbol that represents the assembly being created.

...implying that the compilation object represents the compilation of a single project.

For my use-case, I'm trying to add a new source file to each project that fits a certain criterion (references a particular assembly), so I'm not sure how to proceed when the generator is only provided with a single compilation object, and that compilation object seems to only refer to one assembly.

So my main question is:
*What is going on here, given that an incremental generator is run once for multiple projects, but the compilation object seems to refer to a single project?*

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but, based on terminology, it sounds to me analogous to having a baseball pitcher walking to the mound once and then throwing multiple pitches. There's one pitcher, he is initialised once and then uses individual pitches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Compilation` object indeed represents a single compilation. But if multiple projects reference the generator, the generator is going to run for all those different compilations, even if the host chooses to call `Initialize` once.

What is defined in `Initialize` is a "pipeline", so the pipeline itself will be executed for all projects/compilations that reference the generator.

Meaning that the host only needs to call `Initialize` once to figure out the pipeline, but then the pipeline itself is called as necessary.